# while loop to update dates in DB only updates first row?

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have no idea why this won't work.

```
function query($sql) {
```

```
     $this->result = @mysql_query($sql, $this->conn);

     return($this->result != false);

}
```

function convert() {
        $this->db->open();
        $sql_update = "";
        $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ACCOUNTS ");
        $str = '';
        while ($row = $this->db->fetchassoc()) {
            $jobNum = $row['JOBNUMBER'];
            $old_date = $row['INSTALLDATE'];
            $new_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($old_date));
            $sql_update = "UPDATE ACCOUNTS SET INSTALLDATE='$new_date' WHERE JOBNUMBER='$jobNum' ";
            //$this->db->query($sql_update) or die($this->response->throwResponseError(MSG_DATABASE_ERROR . mysql_error()));
            $str .= $jobNum . " -- " . $new_date . "
";
        }

```
    return $str;
}
```

If I run it with that line commented out, it returns all the results i want. But when I uncomment the line where it actually runs the update, it updates the first record and stops the loop.  Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run update, it invalidates the hidden statement hander in your `db` and the results associated with it.

```
db->query("SELECT …") -- creates the handler

-- 1st iteration
db->fetchassoc() -- fetches the first row
db->query("UPDATE …") -- creates another handler and destroys the old one

-- 2nd iteration
db->fetchassoc() -- no rows returned by `UPDATE`, nothing to fetch
```

What you are trying to do, can be done more easily using a single statement:

```
UPDATE  accounts
SET     installed = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(installed, @current_format_string), '%Y-%d-%m')
```

, where `@current_format_string` is how your dates are formatted now.

**Update:**

Try running this query:

```
UPDATE  accounts
SET     installdate = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(installdate , '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y-%d-%m')
```

Before you run `UPDATE` query, you may want to check the results with `SELECT`:

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(installdate, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y-%d-%m')
FROM    accounts
```

Comment: so would i be better off pushing all the vars into an array and then doing a for each? or how can i fix it?

Comment: PERFECT. I've honestly spent a few hours and couldn't see what was interfering. thank you so much!

Comment: `@mlebrun15`: what is really better is that you do it on the `MySQL` side as show in the post.

Comment: it keeps setting the values to null. is your var "installed", thats supposed to be the same as the column name right?

Comment: Yes. Could you please post some rows that are contained in the table now?

Comment: the column is set up so all the days are in n/j/Y so 6/23/2009 or 12/2/2009, doesn't str_to_time return a value in Y-m-d? i only ask because, this is what i'd like to convert the date to so i technically wouldn't need the DATE FORMAT correct?

Comment: it doesn't recognize INSTALLDATE as a field? when i check it with the select statement? get undefined index errors.

Comment: `@mlebrun15`: sorry, I read your field name incorrectly. Try now.

Comment: yea, i fixed that, and it still is showing nulls, how do i check the select statement?

Comment: hm. i figured it out. i had 

<pre><code>DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(installdate, '%n/%d/%Y'), '%Y-%d-%m')</code></pre>

then i switched to

<pre><code>DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(installdate, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y-%d-%m')</code></pre>

you can't use %n in teh str_to_date function?

Comment: figured that out too the php date var of %n = %c in mysql if anyone else comes across this.